# clientaccesspolicy.xml not getting downloaded from apache server

Tags: silverlight, apache

I have a silverlight web application and from there I am trying to access a .jsp page which is residing in an apache server. Looks like I need clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomainpolicy.xml in the root directory of apache. But I am not sure on what the root directory in apache server will look like. Can anyone throw some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

the root dir is normally your htdocs directory. 
You can look it up in your httpd.conf, it is the DocumentRoot.

BR,

TJ

Comment: I can neither the htdocs directory nor the httpd.conf. I searched the file using windows search. :(

Comment: It is in your conf dir in the apache folder (e.g. C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf).

Comment: @Saravan: Did you find the file?